# im recieving a empty json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm receiving an empty JSON object when posting to the route
`/api/register`

with a JSON object of

```
{
    "username":"test2",
    "password":"1234567"
}
```

I'm trying to console.log the req.body

```
const UserModel = require("./Server/models/User")
const Post = require("./Server/models/Post")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    res.send("Home")
})

app.get("/api/register",(req,res)=> {
    res.send("register")
})


app.post("/api/register",(req,res)=> {
    console.log("recieved")
    console.log(req.body)
})




app.listen(3001,()=> {
    console.log("listening on port 3001")
})
```

Front-end

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
const [username,setUsername] = useState("")
const [password,setPassword] = useState("")


function handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault
fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/register",{
  method:"post",
  headers:{
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  },
  body:JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password})
})


} 



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <input placeholder="username" value={username} onChange={ e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
        <input placeholder="password " value={password} onChange={ e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <button  type='submit' >Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you give more context/code on how you call your API?

Comment: can you show us the frontend part

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending back anything from post endpoint. You should do it like this.

```
app.post("/api/register",(req,res)=> {
    console.log("recieved")
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

In this case we send back the data that user sends.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not sending anything from your API. You can use .send() function to send data back to the caller.
Also, please edit the question and specify where do you expect json printing (console, webpage etc.)

Comment: This answer should be wrote on comment